# How to import a class after creating an ASP.NET Core 7 empty web project in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core-7.0

I created a project using the cmd line:

```
dotnet new web -o TodoApi
```

I then created . `./Models/Todo.cs` class, and I would like to import it in my `./Program.cs` file at the root of my project.

this is my class file:

```
using System;

namespace TodoApi.Models
{
    public class Todo
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It seems using the import `using TodoApi.Models` in the `Program.cs` doesn't do anything.

How should I go about being able to do some import in such a project creation?

I may say that the code compiles and builds, it works. But in Visual Studio 2022 IDE, I don't get suggestions when I start typing the `using TodoApi...` and if I use the class in the Program file, it is not recognized as being a type with set attributes...

Comment: Is it in your project file, in a Models folder?

Comment: Your class Todo is public so you cann access it from your code, no need to import

Answer (score 1):

To access your class in the program file you have to append the whole namespace before the class like:

```cs
TodoApi.Models.Todo Todo = new TodoApi.Models.Todo();
```

If that's too long to write, use namespace [ALIASES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#code-try-1) by importing the class at the top like:

```
using Todo = TodoApi.Models.Todo;
```

This way you can just write Todo class in your program file without appending the namespace to it.

Comment: Or just put a `using TodoApi.Models;` at the top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

So I believe I was doing everything right, and the issue was just  the IDE, Visual Studio, "issue".
After getting back to it (refreshing Visual Studio), my `Todo` class in my file was recognized.

So by using the namespace and the imports properly, you may need to restart your application for it to be recognized as such.

Thanks for the input!